# Pegar todos os src contidos no documento e transformar em array no jquery

Tags: jquery

Supondo que eu tenha 10 elementos img na minha pagina. Gostaria entao de criar um array que tivesse como conteudo os attr-src de cada img contido nessa mesma pagina. Como realizo tal tarefa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando:

```
<img src="image1" />
<img src="image2" />
<img src="image3" />
```

Usando javascript puro:

```
var
  srcs = [],
  images = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
  imagesLength = images.length,
  index = 0;

for ( index; index < imagesLength; index++ ) 
{
  srcs[ index ] = images[ index ].src; 
}

console.log( srcs ); // [ 'image1', 'image2', 'image3' ]
```

Usando Jquery:

```
var
  srcs = [],
  images = $('img');

images.each( function ( index ) 
{
  srcs[ index ] = $( this ).attr('src')
} );

console.log( srcs ); // [ 'image1', 'image2', 'image3' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer assim:

```
var urls = $('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Se precisares da array em formato nativo junta `.get();` ao final.

Podes fazer isso em JavaScript também, sem jQuery:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var urls = [].map.call(imagens, function(img){
    return img.src;
});
```

### Notas:

#### #1

Quer no jQuery quer no JavaScript nativo, o método semanticamente correto é o `.map()`. Eles são parecidos e transformam uma array noutra, substituindo cada elemento da array pelo que é retornado no `return`.

#### #2

Se usares `return img.src;` vais receber o url completo. Se usares `return img.getAttribute('src');` vais receber o que está no HTML, sem ser transformado em url completo.